# Excel auto-sizes column to display scientific notation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a CSV file that I've opened in Excel. It has some numbers.

I enter a formula that refers to some of the existing cells. (The formula value is -9.64669E-06, so it displays in scientific notation, although the source numbers are in decimal notation.)

As soon as I press [Enter], the column grows to display the result to five decimal places.

But if I pre-format the formula cell as `Scientific`, Excel gives just two decimal places and doesn't auto-grow the column.

How can I stop the auto-sizing? My workaround now is to undo entering the formula, format the cell, and re-enter the formula, but this is really dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the function:

=ROUND(A1,2)

[image]

Comment: I still like my original workaround better. It doesn't affect the value of the cell, and doesn't require me to refer to the value to figure out how many decimal places I want.